# How to refresh list in Angular2(v.4) after change any item?

Tags: angular

I have 
**service**:

```
  modCountry(country: Country): Observable<any> {
    let headers = new Headers({'content-type':'application/json;charset=utf-8'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
    return this.http
      .post('http://localhost/my-app/src/core/literature/model/m_country.php', { country }, options)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }  
  getCountries(viewName: string): Observable<Country[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.viewPath+viewName)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

**component**:

```
  getCountries(): void {
    this.literatureService.getCountries('v_country.php')
      .subscribe(countries => this.countries = countries);
  }
  countrySubmit(): void {
    this.literatureService.modCountry(this.countryEditForm.value)
      .subscribe((country) => {
        console.log(country);
      });
    this.visibility.countryE = 'inactive';
    this.visibility.countryL = 'active';
    getCountries();
  }
```

**template**

```
<div id="country_mod">
  <h1 (click)="toggleForm('country');">country</h1>
  <fieldset id="country_list" [@countryChangedL]="visibility.countryL">
    <form>
      <div class="list_item_mini" *ngFor="let country of countries;">
        <span class="list_item_caption_mini" (click)="getCountry(country.id)">{{country.caption}}</span>
        <div class="del_button" (click)="delCountry()"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset id="country_edit" *ngIf="visibility.countryE == 'active'" [@countryChangedE]="visibility.countryE">
    <form [formGroup]="countryEditForm"  (submit)="countrySubmit();">
      <input class="form_control_mini" type="text" formControlName="id" hidden>
      <input class="form_control_mini" type="text" placeholder="Caption" formControlName="caption">
      <input class="form_control_mini" type="text" placeholder="Language" formControlName="language">
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Ok" (click)="countrySubmit();">
      <input type="reset" value="New">
    </form>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

**Logic**: I change any country and close changeForm. In countrySubmit I need to call getCountries() for refresh my list and render it with changes, but my problem is getCountries calls before changes and it does not working.

Please, describe how to do this correctly. How to refresh it?
Or I do it absolutely wrong?
Thanks for answers.

Comment: I didn't see you called `getCountries()` in `countrySubmit`.

Comment: yes, sorry, it was old version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `switchMap` to create another Observable after the first one ended, see [documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap).

```
 this.literatureService.modCountry(this.countryEditForm.value)
 .switchMap(() => this.literatureService.getCountries('v_country.php')) 
 .subscribe((country) => {
   console.log(country);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I had tried to do it with Observables switchMap, but it did my-app slower and more difficult. In the end I rechecked my json and found mistakes in response. I chose decision like this:


` countrySubmit(): void {
     this.literatureService.modCountry(this.countryEditForm.value)
       .catch(err => {return err})
       .subscribe(() => {this.getCountries()});
    this.visibility.countryE = 'inactive';
    this.visibility.countryL = 'active';
  }`